# Kiwi TCMS is saying i need to fill in the base_url when I "Report" a Github issue eventhough that field is populated

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm using Kiwi TCMS version 6.2 in a docker-compose environment. Just trialing it right now.

All working OK in relation to created/edit/delete/run features.

However, I'm also trying to get the Github integration working so that I can create Github issues from within a test case run.

When I click the "Report" link it shows me my Github integration in the dropdown, I click Report button and this error is shown:
"Enable reporting to this Issue Tracker by configuring its base_url!"

In the "Bug Tracker" admin page I have it filled out as follows

Type Github

Base URL https://FQDN/ORG/repo/

APU URL blank

API username blank

API password or Token -  A token that I generated from my Github account via Settings-->Developer Settings-->Personal Access Tokens

I have looked at the Kiwi console by starting docker-compose without the "-d" option and I dont see anything useful in the console.

Any thoughts on what I've done wrong or missing?
Is my token generated from the wrong place maybe?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.GitHub

Base_url:

```
URL to a GitHub repository for which we’re going to report issues
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Yes, I've been following that section of the docs and I have the base_url field populated as per my original post.